# Angular 13: Error: Transform failed with 1 error

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, node-sass

When I was upgrading to Angular 13 I ran into the following errors:

```
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
D:/LevaData UI/customer-portal/src/app/modules/authentication/login/login.component.sass:17:100: ERROR: Unterminated string token
    at D:\LevaData UI\customer-portal\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:81:18
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
D:/LevaData UI/customer-portal/src/app/modules/authentication/login/login.component.sass:17:100: ERROR: Unterminated string token
    at D:\LevaData UI\customer-portal\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:81:18
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

I'm using the following dependencies:

```
  "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^13.3.12",

 "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
 "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
 "sass": "^1.56.0"
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve these issues?

Comment: Can you share your actual code from the `login.component.sass`? The error points to an unterminated string